# Ubuntu Will not Recognise my Samsung C5220 Phone

Tags: wine, samsung, modem, phone

I'm trying to use my Samsung C5220 mobile phone as a modem.

I've installed Samsung PC Studio using Wine but it does not recognise the phone as being connected.

I have done lsusb in a terminal window and see that Ubuntu is recognising the phone as being connected as "Bus 003 Device 006: ID 04e8:6601 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Mobile Phone".

Can anyone advise how I can get the two to meet?

Please bear in mind that I'm a bit of a troglodyte wrt technology so the simplest solution would be best.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you need PC Studio to use that phone as a modem? With Android devices, it is not necessary, and if I remember well, it wasn't with my old Motorola V3x either. Just try to switch on the modem connection on the phone. If nothing happens, connect your phone and look into your connections (using the applet on the top panel which you use also to connect to wifi networks) and check if there is some new entry related to your phone.